# Como personalizar boton en SweetAlert2?

Tags: css, sweetalert2

Es mi primera vez usando `Sweetalert` 2 y ando revisando su página.

A lo mejor soy yo, pero no entiendo como cambiar algunos atributos. Lo he manejado, hasta que llegue a esto, es el `box-shadow` del botón para confirmar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro quitarlo o cambiarlo. Intente con esto, pero no funciona.

```
.swal2-popup .swal2-styled:focus {
  box-shadow: none !important;
 }

.swal2-confirm .swal2-styled .swal2-default-outline:focus{
  box-shadow: none !important;
 }

.swal2-styled.swal2-confirm:focus{
  box-shadow: none !important;
 }
```

Comment: Puedes poner todo el código y cual es el resultado esperado?

Comment: agrega el codigo de tu sweetalert en javascriopt, no solamente el css

Comment: Déjanos saber si la respuesta fue útil o si necesitas información adicional, por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Básicamente se requieren estas dos reglas en un archivo `CSS` local y debe ser importado **después de importar los estilos de `sweetAlert`**:

```
.swal2-styled {
  transition: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Te dejo un snippet de prueba.

```js
function executeExample() {
  Swal.fire({
    title: 'Do you want to save the changes?',
    showDenyButton: true,
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonText: 'Save',
    denyButtonText: `Don't save`,
  }).then((result) => {
    /* Read more about isConfirmed, isDenied below */
    if (result.isConfirmed) {
      Swal.fire('Saved!', '', 'success')
    } else if (result.isDenied) {
      Swal.fire('Changes are not saved', '', 'info')
    }
  })
}
```

```css
/* Este bloque es solo para dar los estilos al botón en el snippet */
.show-example-btn {
    padding: 0.9em 2.1875em;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0.1875em;
    background-color: #7066e0;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.125em;
    font-weight: 500;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Este es el bloque importante */
.swal2-styled {
  transition: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.7.3/dist/sweetalert2.min.css
" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.7.3/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js
"></script>
<!--  Aquí debería ser importado el CSS local -->
<button class="show-example-btn" aria-label="Try me! Example: A dialog with three buttons" onclick="executeExample()">
    Try me!
</button>
```